# Can't configure Hibernate 2nd level cache for EhCache 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jcache, ehcache-3

I use `ehcache.xml` for configuration, it works fine but I'm unable to configure settings for Hibernate 2nd level:

My `application.ml`:

```yaml
    cache:
        jcache.config: classpath:ehcache.xml
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            id.new_generator_mappings: true
            cache:
                use_second_level_cache: true
                region.factory_class: jcache
                use_query_cache: true
            javax:
                cache.provider: org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
                cache.uri: classpath:ehcache.xml
            generate_statistics: true
```

`ehcache.xml`:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
        xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107">
    <service>
        <jsr107:defaults enable-statistics="true" enable-management="true"/>
    </service>
    <cache-template name="default">
        <key-type>java.lang.Object</key-type>
        <value-type>java.lang.Object</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">
                1
            </ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap>100</heap>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>
    <cache alias="com.managestudent.model.Religion" uses-template="default">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">5</ttl>
        </expiry>
    </cache>
    <cache alias="religion" uses-template="default">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">5</ttl>
        </expiry>
    </cache>
</config>
```

Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "religion")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "religion")
public class Religion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String religionName;
```

I tried both `region="religion"` with `<cache alias="religion"/>` or use full path name `com.managestudent.model.Religion` both doesn't work.

Edit: Also the cache gets PUT but no miss reported when I trigger `GET /religion/all` but not `GET /religion/{id}` despite having `use_query_cache :true`